# Поддерживают ли браузеры функцию preventDefault и является ли она стандартной?

Tags: javascript, события

Читаю на ночь глядя книгу по `JavaScript` и там в обработчике события `onsubmit` вызывается функция `preventDefault`, которая согласно написанному в книге отменяет действие по умолчанию для данного события:

```
addForm.onsubmit = function (e) {
    preventDefault(e);
    // ,,,
```

Однако, например, `IE 11` указывает, что такой функции нет.

Поэтому так как в книге о поддержке этой функции ничего не говорится, хотелось бы получить ответ, действительно это - стандартная функция, и просто не все браузеры ее поддерживают, или здесь вкралось какое-то недоразумение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`preventDefault` это метод прототипа Event, поэтому он должен вызываться так:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Метод стандартный, в IE появился в версии 9 (в версиях меньше 9 использовалось свойство `returnValue`, которое надо устанавливить в `false`, чтобы отменить event).

Либо в книге ошибка, либо авторы ранее определяют глобальную функцию `preventDefault`, возможно для поддержки старых версий IE:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  else
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```